# How can I fix this buildozer build error?

Tags: android, python-3.x, debugging, kivy, buildozer

I'm getting an error while trying to build a kivy app into apk on buildozer, I'll show you the logs:

```
Listing '/home/pedro/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/app/git-2.20.0/vcs-svn'...
Compiling '/home/pedro/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/app/main.py'...
Compiling '/home/pedro/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.py'...
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Error while running "/home/pedro/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 -OO -m compileall -b -f /home/pedro/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/app"
This probably means one of your Python files has a syntax error, see logs above
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --bootstrap sdl2 --dist_name kivy_example --name KivyExample --version 0.1 --package org.kivy_example.kivy_example --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/pedro/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/pedro/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     LANGUAGE = 'pt_BR:pt:en'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     LANG = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin'
#     MAIL = '/var/mail/root'
#     LOGNAME = 'root'
#     USER = 'root'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SUDO_COMMAND = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer android debug'
#     SUDO_USER = 'pedro'
#     SUDO_UID = '1000'
#     SUDO_GID = '1000'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '30'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `Python files has a syntax error` . Try to run main.py before compile and find error.

Comment: i've already executed it, and works fine =(

Comment: Is your local python version equel to buildozer python version ? If so, you should add minimal code and buildozer file .

Comment: how can i check my buildozer python version? idk

Comment: In buildozer.spec file `osx.python_version` and `osx.kivy_version` let you set versions.

Comment: they're different python: 3.0 and kivy: 2.0.0

Comment: Did you test your code in python version 2 or version 3 ? Share minimal code which you tested to compile so we can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same error as you before and apparently I have been using the old version of cython (version 0.29.19) so I changed it
from
`!pip install cython==0.29.19`  to
`!install -U cython`
so make sure you have the latest cython version after you run the
`!pip install buildozer`
command on your colab document

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same error as you before and apparently I have been using the old version of cython (version 0.29.19) so I changed it from !pip install cython==0.29.19 to !install -U cython so make sure you have the latest cython version after you run the !pip install buildozer command on your colab document