# Python Kivy Not Exporting to APK

Tags: python, android, rspec, buildozer

I want to be able to turn my Kivy file into an APK file for android, when I run `buildozer -v android debug`, and which it creates a bin folder with nothing contained with it. I'm using Ubuntu. Here is my spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (leave empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (list) Application requirements
requirements = python3,kivy

# (list) Supported orientations
orientation = portrait

# (list) Android specific configurations
fullscreen = 0
android.api = 31
android.minapi = 21
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a
android.allow_backup = True
# Add more Android configurations as needed

[buildozer]

# Buildozer specific configurations
log_level = 2
warn_on_root = 1
# Add more Buildozer configurations as needed
```

I expected an APK file to show in the bin, 'applibs' with 'state.db' were created, but not the APK file. Ask me if you need more information.

I've tried exporting sample project, downloading packages, and more with no change in results if you could help me that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Please add in errors encountered while building. Do search for similar errors like: [Kivy buildozer.spec Error - Trying to build an android App that sends an email out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60963080/295004) and [How can I fix this buildozer build error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72589432/295004) to see if anything might be useful. Do write down what you tried along with any changes.